# Why does CodeIgniter force classes to have their first letter capitalised?

Tags: php, codeigniter, coding-style, naming-conventions

As per the [creating libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html) documentation:

```
File names must be capitalized. For example:  Myclass.php
Class declarations must be capitalized. For example:  class Myclass
```

Why is this? Once it's loaded as a property (e.g. `$this->myclass->do_something()`) it's lowercased anyway.

Answer (score 2):

that "myclass" thingy (`$this->myclass`) is an **instance** of the class, not a class.

Instances / objects are lowercase, but the class is uppercase. Calling a static function would go like `Myclass::do_something_statically()` (notice the uppercase).

So the lowercase thing is something else, and making the class upcase will let you see the difference :)

Comment: I understand that. I'm wondering why the convention is to have the filename uppercase, why not just stick with lowercase since that's how it's going to be used anyway.

Comment: Probably because of backward compatibility. And maybe to streamline coding style between developers.

Comment: But it isn't going to be used lowercase. The filename is the name of the class, and you use that uppercase, that's the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe for the same reason German capitalizes nouns.

It make it more easy for human readers to 'parse' the text.